# How can I compute the tensor in Pytorch efficiently?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a tensor `x` and `x.shape=(batch_size,10)`, now I want to take

```py
 x[i][0] = x[i][0]*x[i][1]*...*x[i][9] for i in range(batch_size)
```

Here is my code:

```py
for i in range(batch_size):
    for k in range(1, 10):
        x[i][0] = x[i][0] * x[i][k]
```

But when I implement this in `forward()` and call `loss.backward()`, the speed of back-propagation is very slow. Why is it slow and is there any way to implement it efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is slow because you use two for loops.

You can use `.prod` See: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.prod

In your case,

`x = torch.prod(x, dim=1)` or `x = x.prod(dim=1)`

should work

Comment: It works when x[i][j] is a scalar. Now my x[i][j] is a matrix, this is just an element-wise multiplication,I want to compute x[i][0]= x[i][0].matmul(x[i][1]).matmul(x[i][2])...... Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: In that case, you might have to use the inner-loop but you can avoid outer loop by using `torch.bmm` for multiplication. pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.bmm

Answer (score 1):

When you are using two loops to compute the product, the complexity is n^2. Imagine doing this many times during back-propagation and your code becomes slow.

Vector operations speed up these computations, since they can be parallelized.

Comment: the computation complexity won't change even when vectorized. It is just that vectorized operations can be parallelized and hence faster on modern machines